# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (6243, 256, 256)

Tags: python, keras

I want to append the label on the training dataset and I do it as

```
def one_hot_label(img):
    label = img
    if label == 'A':
        ohl = np.array([1, 0])
    elif label == 'B':
        ohl = np.array([0, 1])
    return ohl

def train_data_with_label():
    train_images = []
    for i in tqdm(os.listdir(train_data)):
        path_pre = os.path.join(train_data, i)
        for img in os.listdir(path_pre):
            if img.endswith('.jpg'):
                path = os.path.join(path_pre, img)
                img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                train_images.append([np.array(img), one_hot_label(i)])
    shuffle(train_images)
    return train_images
```

However, the error returned when execute the input on Keras

```
training_images = train_data_with_label()
tr_img_data = np.array([i[0] for i in training_images])
tr_lbl_data = np.array([i[1] for i in training_images])

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))
```

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked how `numpy.append` behaves for multidimensional arrays?https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

Comment: the return like this 
[array([[231, 234, 235, ..., 238, 239, 240],
       [233, 235, 235, ..., 234, 237, 240],
       [229, 231, 231, ..., 227, 230, 233],
       ...,
       [218, 217, 222, ..., 193, 197, 224],
       [213, 212, 217, ..., 198, 200, 228],
       [210, 209, 214, ..., 206, 208, 236]], dtype=uint8), array([1, 0])]

Comment: I am not sure the how the input layer handle the array on the back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input layer is expecting an array of shape `(batch_size, 256, 256, 1)` but it looks like you are passing in data of the shape `(batch_size, 256, 256)`. You can try reshaping your training data as follows:

```
tr_img_data = np.expand_dims(tr_img_data, axis=-1)
```